# Can the Unity Game Engine go completely fullscreen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, dart, virtual-reality

I have seen pictures where the Unity Game Engine is a part of the Flutter application but the AppBar seems to still be there. I am yet to investigate but is it possible to remove the AppBar and make the Unity Camera View paired with VR go fullscreen?

Comment: By fullscreen, I mean like the camera view in Snapchat where the camera goes from the top of the screen to the bottom and extends to the sides.

Comment: Do you want Unity Engine to open camera full screened in your Flutter app? Why not to add screen, of the thing you want to make